# Run function after beforeEach

Tags: mocha.js

I need to run a function before my tests, but after all beforeEaches. Is there a way of prioritise beforeEaches, reorder them or monkeypatching something so that I can run a function before test gets executed?

Reason: I want to count how many database calls my tests do, but not include those that beforeEach calls.

Answer (score 0):

Mocha executes the `beforeEach` hooks that pertain to a test in the order in which it encountered them in your code, so there should not be a need to monkeypatch. For instance:

```
describe("top", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        console.log("A");
    });

    describe("down", () => {

        beforeEach(() => {
            console.log("B");
        });

        beforeEach(() => {
            console.log("C");
            // Put your code here.
        });

        it("test 1", () => {});
        it("test 2", () => {});
    });
});
```

The above outputs:

```
  top
    down
A
B
C   
      ✓ test 1
A
B
C   
      ✓ test 2
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to do that for all my 1000 tests. So I would need a afterBeforeEach that would run every time after all beforeEaches

Comment: There could be 1000 tests in the inner `describe`.

Comment: But I have more describes inside that, that have own beforeEaches that will be run after the `console.log('c')`-beforeEach